# Unable to start mysqld service after enabling log_bin

Tags: mysql, replication, binlog, mysqlbinlog, mysqld

Hi I am unable to start mysqld service after I make changes in my.cnf to enable log-bin.
After making changes the file looks like below:

```
# For advice on how to change settings please see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-configuration-defaults.html

[mysqld]
#
# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M
#
# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin

#This is what I added to enable log-bin

log-bin=/var/log/mysql/
log-bin-index=bin-log.index
max_binlog_size=100M
binlog_format=row
socket=mysql.sock

#That was what I added to enable log-bin
#
# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

I am using:

```
[ec2-user@pip my.cnf.d]$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo)
```

Following is the ownership and permissions:

```
d]$ ls -ld /var/log/mysql
drwxrwxrwx. 2 mysql mysql 23 Sep  8 09:01 /var/log/mysql
```

Following is the error that I get:

```
[ec2-user@i.d]$ sudo service mysqld start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  mysqld.service
Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

MySQL version is:

```
Server version: 5.7.19 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Please let me know if any other detail is required

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but note the `log_bin` is not the same as `log-bin`.

Comment: This is related to binary log in MySQL which is used for database recovery

Comment: My point was, the `my.cnf` file has a commented reference to `log` *underscore* `bin`, while you've set up `log` *dash* `bin` wanted to be sure that the problem isn't a simple typo there. If you already got that, my apologies.

Comment: What was in mysqld's error log?

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity, is mysqld actually down ??? If you are not sure, please run `service mysqld status`.

Comment: By the way, what is the actual error code ???

Comment: @RDFozz I need binary logs to be enabled, please explain accordingly

Comment: @Kitty - As per my last comment; I was noting what might have been a typo (`log-bin` instead of `log_bin`), coming out of my review of your post. If `log-bin` is the correct way to set it up, then my comments can be removed. I'd focus on the comments from Rick James and RolandoMySQLDBA, at this point. I can't help with the actual configuration - I use MySQL very little, and have played with the configuration side not at all.

Comment: also you've specified `socket` a second time, the last instance is the one used, but its a little odd to list it twice.

Comment: You may need so set the [selinux context](https://blogs.oracle.com/jsmyth/selinux-and-mysql) on /var/log/mysql (`semanage fcontext -a -t mysqld_db_t "/var/log/mysql(/.*)?" && restorecon -Rv /var/log/mysql`). As others have asked for the error log, which would confirm this or other many other possible accurate answers, so this is just a guess. `service mysqld status` or `journalctl -n 50 -u mysql.service` will show the error log.

Answer (score 4):

According to [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#option_mysqld_log-bin) entry for the `mysqld` option `log-bin`:

> If you specify this option without also specifying a `--server-id`, the server is not allowed to start.

So it seems you need something like:

```
[mysqld]
server-id=1
log-bin
```